# Multiplication of GP and HP

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Can we find the sum of series,
>   $$\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 5^2}+ \frac{1}{3\cdot 5^3}+\dots $$.

If this 2,3 were in numerator , then this is AGP, 
which we know how to solve, by multilying by common 
ratio and shifting one term to left. But same approach 
is not working here.

Comment: See the Taylor expansion of $-\log(1-x)$ or integration term by term of a geometric series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, the Maclaurin series for $-\log(1-x)$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k=x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\dots\qquad|x|<1$$
Now take $x=\frac15$.